# Sp-api - seller partner api python

Tags: python, boto3, amazon-mws

I want to connect to the seller partner api in **python** using **boto3**.

The steps `assumeRole` to get temporary credentials for a session client I get. But `sp-api` is not in the list of aws services to handle with **boto3**. Is there a reference for the `sp-api` to use with python or what would be the equivalent to `s3 = boto3.client('s3')` for the `sp-api`?

Comment: There’s a pretty complete package available: https://github.com/saleweaver/python-amazon-sp-api

Answer (score 7):

I had also issues and questions like you have, I managed to connect successfully, maybe this can help:

```
import boto3
# ======== GET AUTH ========
# Credentials for user created following the docs
amw_client = boto3.client(
    'sts',
    aws_access_key_id=self.access_key,
    aws_secret_access_key=self.secret_key,
    region_name=self.region
)
# ROLE created following the docs
# STS assume policy must be included in the role
res = amw_client.assume_role(
    RoleArn='arn:aws:iam::xxxx:role/xxxx',
    RoleSessionName='SellingPartnerAPI'
)

Credentials = res["Credentials"]
AccessKeyId = Credentials["AccessKeyId"]
SecretAccessKey = Credentials["SecretAccessKey"]
SessionToken = Credentials["SessionToken"]

from requests_auth_aws_sigv4 import AWSSigV4

aws_auth = AWSSigV4('execute-api',
                    aws_access_key_id=AccessKeyId,
                    aws_secret_access_key=SecretAccessKey,
                    aws_session_token=SessionToken,
                    region=self.region
                    )

import requests
# ======== GET ACCESS TOKEN ======
body = \
    {
        'grant_type': 'refresh_token',
        'client_id': amazon_app_client_id,
        'refresh_token': amazon_app_refresh_token,
        'client_secret': amazon_app_client_secret
    }

h = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
access_token_response = \
    requests.post('https://api.amazon.com/auth/o2/token', json=body, headers=h)
access_token = self.access_token_response.json().get('access_token')


# ======== CONSUME API ========
resp = requests.get(
request_url, auth=aws_auth, headers={'x-amz-access-token': access_token})
```

Let me know if I can help further :)

Comment: what's the `access_token` here within the last line in code?

Comment: also i think that you meant `auth=aws_auth` ?

Comment: you were correct it was `auth=aws_auth` and I added part of the code to get access_token :) hope this explains all you need

Answer (score 0):

In 2023 you can call without AWS auth if your app is setup correctly according to the [registration overview](https://developer-docs.amazon.com/sp-api/docs/sp-api-registration-overview) (code sample refactored from @ky_aaaa's answer in this thread):

```
def get_access_token():
    body = \
        {
            'grant_type': 'refresh_token',
            'client_id': client_id,
            'refresh_token': refresh_token,
            'client_secret': client_secret
        }

    h = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    access_token_response = requests.post('https://api.amazon.com/auth/o2/token', json=body, headers=h)
    access_token = access_token_response.json().get('access_token')  
    
    return access_token 

report_status_url = 'https://sellingpartnerapi-na.amazon.com/reports/2021-06-30/reports/{}'
headers={'x-amz-access-token': get_access_token()}
resp = requests.get(report_status_url.format(reportId), headers=headers)
```